# Trying to run Code::Blocks on Ubuntu with wxWidgets

Tags: installation, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I've just installed CB (Code::Blocks) 10,05 and also installed wxWidgets from the repos. I am trying to simply compile and run a blank form. But this does not seem to work. I get the error:

> /usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/cursor.h error: ‘wxIsBusy’ was not declared in this scope

What I've tried so far:

1. Installed libwxbase 2.8 lib and dev files
2. Restarted CB
3. Installed codeblocks-contrib

I've tried some solutions from forums but nothing seems to work. Now I get the error as mentioned above.

Can someone please direct me towards a fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying so many forums (on different sites), I finally did one desperate install. I went on to the software center and searched for wxsmith. I simply checked everything that was not installed.

I believe the trick was in this package: "Dummy transitional package for wxSmith development files" (libwxsmithlib0-dev). Along with it another package also got installed.

So, I did not reinstall everything but just the one(s) mentioned above in this answer. then I restarted CB and it compiled and run like a breeze!